# ORA-00911 error with to_date function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

This request works as intended:

```
select dit_in.id data_item_in, dit_out.id data_item_out, alg.id algo_id 

from algorithm_run arun

join algorithm_run_of arof on
arof.algorithm_run_id = arun.id

join algorithm_run_input arin on
arin.algorithm_run_id = arun.id

join data_item dit_in on
dit_in.id = arin.data_item_id

join algorithm alg on
alg.id = arof.algorithm_id

join algorithm_run_output arout on
arout.algorithm_run_id = arun.id

join data_item dit_out on
dit_out.id = arout.data_item_id

where alg.id in (182,183,143,162,125,222)
```

Unfortunately I get an error when I add at the end:

```
 and arun.start_time >= to_date(’01/jun/2011’,’dd/mm/yyyy’) 
 and arun.start_time < to_date(’01/jul/2011’,’dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I'm using a web interface, the error message is:

> warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00911: invalid character in /opt/csw/apache2/share/htdocs/DAE/sites/default/modules/data_repository/data_repository.inc on line 117.
>
> warning: oci_fetch_row() [function.oci-fetch-row]: ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in /opt/csw/apache2/share/htdocs/DAE/sites/default/modules/daedatabase/daedatabase_db.inc on line 852.

Comment: Explain "starts failing". If it gives an error message, post the error message. If it returns the wrong data, describe the data that should be returned vs. what is returned.

Comment: Post edited with the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Phil points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863356/non-fonctionnal-sql-request-using-to-date-fonction/7866490#7866490), your strings are wrapped in two different quotes marks.  It looks like you're mainly use fancy quote marks, from a word processor.  This is a problem, because Oracle is expecting plain ASCII apostrophes (ASCII 39).

It would certainly explain why you're getting an ORA-00911 error.

To fix this, you simply need to replace all the `’` with `'` .

To avoid it in the future you should use a text editor or IDE when writing code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I took the query from a research paper in pdf, wasn't careful enough.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 and arun.start_time >= to_date(’01/06/2011’,’dd/mm/yyyy’) 
 and arun.start_time < to_date(’01/07/2011’,’dd/mm/yyyy’)
```

or

```
 and arun.start_time >= to_date(’01/jun/2011’,’dd/mon/yyyy’) 
 and arun.start_time < to_date(’01/jul/2011’,’dd/mon/yyyy’)
```

The problem is that your date string (01/jun/2011) doesn't match the format specifier (dd/mm/yyyy).   You need to either change your date or the specifier, as the above examples show.

Comment: No that's ok. JUN is automatically valued at 06. And when I put 06, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 5):

```
and arun.start_time < to_date(’01/jul/2011’,’dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Do I see two different types of quote characters around that last bit? A single quote and a backquote?  Or is that just a cut/paste or translation problem?